# Problems with uninstallation of windows 8

Tags: windows-8, operating-systems, multi-boot, uninstall

I installed windows 8's developer preview version dual boot with win 7 ultimate.
I put my win 8's partition to 11 GB (almost), but now when I try to uninstall the win 8 it dont allow me to uninstall it saying `no enough space`.

What to do ??

Then I try to login to win 7 and increase the size of the partition of win 8. This also is not possible.

Please help me with it. I want to uninstall it but how and what to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just delete the partition from Windows 7, after that run msconfig (Windows key + R > type "msconfig" > Enter), switch to the Boot tab, select a list item named "Microsoft Windows 8" or similar and click "Delete", this will get rid of the Boot Manager prompt on boot(otherwise it would ask if you want win7 or win8).
[image]

Comment: Ok I will try this out as I am at present in my office :)

Comment: Does this allow me to undo my partition ie can I able to merge it back to the other partition or unallocated partition ?

Comment: If you mean can you extend the Win7 partition over the deleted partition/unallocated space, the answer is yes.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't you need a tool like gParted for this? I _know_ you do for XP.

Comment: You can [delete and extend](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325590) partitions in XP too, and the msconfig application looks almost the same on all version of Windows.