# Removing old windows from disk?

Tags: windows-8

I have Windows 8 Release Candidate installed on my d:\ partition and RTM installed on the c:\ partition. I want to get rid of the RC on d. I also want the bootloader to stop prompting me about which windows 8 to start. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the extra OS from the boot loader as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/210969/remove-entry-from-windows-7-bootloader). Then you can just delete the files on D: or format it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the D:\ drive. Here are instructions to help you:

http://www.eightforums.com/installation-setup/5857-delete-windows-8-cp-partition.html#post86501

I personally think the last post is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the partition with Device Manager, start by clicking the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Maintenance, and then clicking Device Manager([source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Open-Device-Manager)). Follow these steps below, in your case you'll select D: instead of C:(edit: you can right click on the list directly). [image]
Removing the prompt is described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/493917/problems-with-uninstallation-of-windows-8/493920#493920):  run msconfig (Windows key + R > type "msconfig" > Enter), switch to the Boot tab, select a list item named "Microsoft Windows 8" or similar and click "Delete"[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the one on C:\ is the boot drive, you can just format the D:\ partition in windows to remove the old windows installation in disk management

Comment: That's the obvious, but inconvenient solution. If all else fails, I'll do it.