# Uninstall Invisible OS (Windows 8 Preview) - Appears in boot

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, operating-systems

I've been using Windows 7 for three years now with no other operating systems. When the Windows 8 consumer preview came out last year, I partitioned my hard drive to dual-boot Windows 7 and 8. When the preview ended, I stupidly went and deleted the partition Windows 8 was on instead of uninstalling it however I should have. However, since the free space merged with my existing partition, I didn't think anything of it.

Today, I partitioned my hard drive again to install Ubuntu. It told me it detected multiple OS's (Windows 7 and 8). How do I get rid of Windows 8 completely?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/493920/23133

Comment: @Techie007, can you stick that in the answer box, so the OP can mark it as solved? I'd hate to have it floating around in limbo with the other 10,000 unsolved questions for all eternity.

Comment: Actually, I tried the solution in the link you provided but Windows 8 doesn't show up in msconfig, nor does Ubuntu for that matter.

Comment: Does the Ubuntu installer describe how it detected Windows 7 and 8?

Comment: Not that I can tell. On the boot loader, it shows an icon for Ubuntu and then one for each of the Windows versions

Answer (score 0):

If windows 8 installation is detectable then you can try to repair it and then you can uninstall it. But however if you deleted the installation files you can try to use the BCDedit software to manually remove windows 8 from Boot manager.

Also if windows 8 is undetectable from msconfig.exe it is probably because windows 8 would have been your default windows while booting up and you deleted those files from windows 7 so you might end up with an invisible OS appearing in the boot menu. Also if Ubuntu can detect the installation you can try to install on that partition where windows 8 was so that Ubuntu can delete windows 8 from boot menu and can register itself there.